# Column selection mode (CTRL+V) on vim doesn't work as expected

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, vim

I'm trying to select & edit these text:

```
pick e17a1b1 test 1
pick 37d4ccb test 2
pick c7ab952 test 3
pick 905617f test 4
pick 1c77d56 test 5
pick 1805ffa test 6
```

What I do:

1. `ctrl + v` (not V, because Ubuntu interprets it as paste action);
2. select all `pick` words;
3. `shift + I`;
4. start typing `abc`;
5. `esc`, `esc` ..;
6. from here is either nothing changes (if I type some different characters) or change the only first line.

[image]
[image]

**What do I wrong?**

**UPDATE**

I've tried vim-gnome and doing the same leads to the expected result!

Comment: The changes should appear after you exit edit mode (i.e. press ESC)

Comment: I'm not so stupid. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: didn't want to offend you, but since you didn't explicitly mention it I had to guess. Have you installed vim or vim-nox or are u using vim-tiny?

Comment: Never mind, you are right - you had to). I didn't install anything I just use vim installed by default, running `vim --version` it outputs: `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Oct 20 2014 16:09:34)
Included patches: 1-273
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
`

Comment: try installing vim-nox

Comment: It's a solution!) Now it works!) Post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some troubleshooting with Timur Fayzrakhmanov (see comments on OP) we found the following solution:

Ubuntu comes by default with a stripped down version of vim. In order to get the whole vim functionality, package vim-nox should be installed.

Comment: Correct but strange! Why does ubuntu  install a stripped down version of vim? (vim is not so resource expensive)